# Editing details on a page with a picture

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a page with a picture and few other fields . Uploading picture works fine.If user wants to edit and put a different picture, that works fine too. The problem occurs when user edit  a different field (other than the image field) in the record . After saving , the image disappears.

Here is my controller

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "GlobalMaterialId,Length,Picture")] MetalStock metalStock, HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (ImageFile != null)
            {
                string pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ImageFile.FileName);

                metalStock.ImagePath = pic;

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    ImageFile.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                    metalStock.Picture = ms.GetBuffer();

                }

            }                             

            m_db.Entry(metalStock).State = EntityState.Modified;           

            m_db.SaveChanges();

           return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(metalStock);
    }
```

here is the image uploading bit of the view

<input name="ImageFile" type='file' / >

I understand that when I edit a field and save, ImageFile that is passed to the controller is empty and that creates the problem. I tried few other things such as trying to get the picture from the record and reassigning it to the object etc. Non of them worked. Please help.

Comment: Is that image tag is inside the form ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry . The form begins this way @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "MetalStocks", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess your controller dies because it looks for a HttpPostedFile and does not get one.
You can either make it nullable in the declaration of your action

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "GlobalMaterialId,Length,Picture")] MetalStock metalStock, HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile = null)
```

or don't declare it in the controller at all and pick it up from the Request:

```
var Image = Request.Files["ImageFile"]
```

Comment: Wow! Your first solution worked like a charm :) . Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0):

You could store your existing image file in a hidden field as a base64 string and in your post action check to see if the HttpPostedFileBase is null (they haven't selected a different image). If it is, convert your base64 string back to a byte array and assign it to your  metalStock.Picture property.

This is how I've handled this scenario in the past. You will need to create another property on your viewmodel to hold this base64 string. This is beneficial assuming your view is not bound directly to your entity, but a viewmodel instead.

Comment: Dear Matty ,Thanks heaps for replying.  savanelten's solution worked . However, I would love to learn your way too. Is is possible for you to point me to a tutorial that explains it?